# Was -i used as genitive ending for first declension masculines?

Tags: ancient-greek, declension, morphology, genitive, declinatio-prima

In Greek masculines of the first declension borrow the singular genitive ending *-ου* from second declension.
Latin uses the ending *-ae* for all of first declension: *puellae*, *nautae*, *Anchisae*, *Aeneae*.
There are also occasional genitives similar to the Greek first declension feminine ones (*familias*, *musices*, *Melpomenes*), but these are beside my point.

**Was *-i* ever used as a genitive ending for masculines of the first declension?**
If this happens, it is presumably due to Greek influence, and I suspect it is more likely to happen in words or names of Greek origin.
Despite seeing many Greek loan words, I have never seen this genitive in any text or grammar.
Searches for *nauti* and *Anchisi* give nothing, and *Aenei* gives unrelated hits for the adjective *aēneus*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any reference to such an ending in either Allen and Greenough or Gildersleeve and Lodge, so I strongly suspect the answer is no.

That said, in another, historical sense the *-ī* ending *was* used as a first-declension gen. sg. ending, and not just for masculines. The ending *-ae* is historically formed from *-a-ī*: the *-a-* of the first-declension stem plus the same *-ī* as in the second declension. The earlier spelling of this ending was -AI, which is found in inscriptions and occasionally in poetry where a disyllabic ending was needed for the meter. (This is unlike the case of Greek, where the first- and second-declension gen. sg. endings have different origins.)

Comment: Thanks! If someone miraculously finds examples of the ending *-i*, I will have to unaccept this, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

Sort of, but technically "no".

It seems that *-i* was sometimes used as a genitive singular ending for masculine names from Greek that end in *-ēs* in the nominative. But although many of these come from Greek first-declension nouns, they typically seem to be classified as third-declension rather than first-declension nouns in the context of Latin.

In fact, genitive singular forms in *-i* existed even for some masculine names ending in *-ēs* that weren't from Greek first-declension nouns, such as *Diomedes* (from Greek *Διομήδης, Διομήδους*) and *Hercules* (from Greek *Ἡρακλῆς, Ἡρακλέους,* but not directly: the direct source of Latin *Hercules* is supposed to have been an Etruscan form "Hercle"). Varro mentions the variability between *-i* and *-is* in the genitive singular of these two names in [*De Lingua Latina,* Book 10, §49](https://archive.org/stream/onlatinlanguage02varruoft#page/572/mode/2up).

Even though this irregular use of Latin genitive *-i* looks suggestively similar to the Greek use of *-ου* as a masculine first-declension genitive ending, I can find no evidence that *-i* was ever viewed as a first-declension ending in Latin.

#### Grammars that mention genitive singular forms in *-i* for names in *-es*

[Allen and Greenough §52a](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/2nd-declension-greek-nouns) says that  "Many names in ***-ēs*** belonging to the 3rd declension have also a genitive in ***-ī***", giving the example "Thūcȳdidēs, Thūcȳdidī". This grammar classifies *Thūcȳdidī* as a second-declension form, and *Thūcȳdidēs* as a third-declension form.

*Grammar of the Latin Language,* by C.G. Zumpt (1836), says the following:

- "the greater part of Greek nouns in *ης, ου,* if not patronymics, are declined after the third declension in Latin, as *Alcibiades, Miltiades, Xerxes*"  ([Sect. VII.3, pp. 11-12](https://books.google.com/books?id=-SB0JZzDHD4C&pg=PA11)).
- "Cicero very commonly, and other authors of the best age occasionally, form from Greek nouns proper in *es* a genitive in *i,* instead of *is*; e.g. gr. *Achilli, Ulixi* (see p. 15), *Isocrati, Archimedi,* especially from those in *cles, Agathcli, Diocli, Neocli, Procli, Pericli, Themistocli.* So in the barbarian names *Mithridati, Xerxi,* and others." ([Sect XIII, Remark 1, p. 25-26](https://books.google.com/books?id=-SB0JZzDHD4C&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

In a comment, Draconis mentioned finding a single example of genitive singular *Thūcȳdidī* in Quintilian: "imitator Thucydidi et ut multo infirmior".

---

**Side note:** I have asked a separate question about the use of third-declension forms like
gen. sg. *Thūcȳdidis* for names like this: [How are "Arsaces" and "Gotarzes" declined, and why?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/how-are-arsaces-and-gotarzes-declined-and-why)

Comment: PHI pointed me to Quintilian, who talks about Philistus, "imitator Thucydidi et ut multo infirmior". All other authors seem to use *-is* in the genitive and *-i* in the dative, as you'd expect from the third declension.