# Is the declension of "-ides" on Wiktionary wrong?

Tags: grammar-identification

I found the suffix ***-ides*** tagged as "3rd. decl." on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ides#Suffix_2), with "***-idis***" as its genitive.
But as I learnt, the patronymic suffix ***-ides*** is a Greek-type 1st. decl. suffix (e.g. *L&S*: "***Achillides, -ae***"), is this Wiktionary entry just a mistake?

> Edit: The suffix as in ***Achillides*** has a long *i*, while the suffix on Wiktionary has a short one.

[image]

Comment: If you look, it seems it links to a Medieval Latin name. It's perhaps just been re-analyzed as a normal Latin 3rd-declension noun instead of a proper Greek patronymic.

Comment: I have not done an exhaustive search, but all of the *-ides* nouns with an *-idae* genitive which I have seen, like *achillides*, had had a long i. Is there a distinction to be made between long and short i in *-ides*?

Comment: Often times, names of Greek origin could be used with either Latin or (approximate) Greek endings, in Latin. So I guess I wouldn't be surprised to see this. But I don't know more about this particular suffix.

Comment: I couldn't come to a firm answer, but here is a relevant previous question: [What is the gender and singular declension of the scientific Latin suffix -idae?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17244)